# How to show items as count when ellipsis are active

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, vue-component, vuejs3

I have the following template wherein I am trying to display an array of 'to' ids as string along with the count shown beside. The count is to show the ids count that are hidden with ellipsis as I reduce the window size. Here is the sample UI for that.

For now I have the ellipsis functionality working and the computed property for count returns a hardcoded value. Iam not sure how to display the count based on the above context.

[image]

```
<div
   class="list-item"
   v-for="(item, index) in json"
   :key="index"
>
 <div class="list-item__to">{{getToIds(item.to)}}</div>
 <div class="list-item__notifier">
    <div style="width: 20px; padding: 4px 4px; border-radius: 3px; font-size: 14px; background: gray; color: white;">{{getCount}}
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

```
computed: {
    getToIds () {
      return data => {
        if (data.length === 1) return data[0];
        else {
          let str = '';
          for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
            if (i !== data.length - 1) str += `${data[i]}, `;
            else str += `${data[i]}`;
          }
          return str;
        }
      }
    },
    getCount () {
      return '+1';
    }
  },
```

and my stylings are

```
.list-item {
            display: flex;
            border: 1px solid rgb(230, 228, 228);
            border-left: none;
            border-right: none;
            padding: 15px;
            &:hover {
              color: blue;
              cursor: pointer;
            }
            &__to {
              width: 35%;
              margin-left: 10px;
              white-space: nowrap;
              overflow: hidden;
              text-overflow: ellipsis;
              &:hover {
                text-overflow: clip;
                white-space: normal;
                word-break: break-all;
              }
            }
            &__notifier {
              width: 5%;
              margin-left: 10px;
              font-weight: bold;
            }
          }
```

Comment: Is it some sort of requirement to display the ellipsis dots `…` using CSS? 
Because you might have to calculate the width of your item container and the amount of letters that can be properly displayed using JavaScript that will also take care of dispaying the dots.

Comment: Yes it is, Iam ok with javascript also for the ellipsis functionality

Comment: The thing is I need to get this working..no matter if thats using scss or javascript :)

Comment: Is the container width fixed or dynamic?

Comment: The width is in percentage

Comment: For the containing element too?  i.e. whatever is outside `list-item`

Comment: Yes everything is in percentage